# Kafka v0.9 Running Perf Test

Tags: apache-kafka

Just want to ask help on how to run the producer/consumer perf-test.sh using kafka v 0.9.0

I was able to run perf-test using v 0.8.x but when using v.0.9.x it's using diff options. Tried to look for samples but no luck.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

## newbieKafka